# ASP.NET 5 Error 404 for WebSocket Connection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been diving into ASP.NET 5, and so far it is going pretty well. However, I have been facing the problem of adding the ability to handle WebSocket connections to my server, and have been having a lot of problems. Namely, 404 errors when my JS function tries to connect to the server:

http://pastebin.com/T2S1VtMq My JS file

http://pastebin.com/BjwuaJqe The error on Chrome dev console

http://pastebin.com/r0UzpzN3 DNX console

My site uses the MVC model for the main pages, and etc, but I think I am going to have to create a custom map for /ws, /wss. I attempted to do so by adding an app.Map function to map /ws to a certain function, also defining the functions of that map in startup.cs: http://pastebin.com/m2zDYeex

I assume that you don't need to create a controller for this in the controllers folder, since it already has all the response defined in it. I tried adding a controller, but this didn't seem to change the program.

From debugging, the most I can guess is that the if function on line 112 of startup.cs is returning false, causing the lack of response, thus a 404 error. I added two debug lines, one just outside the if on line 111 (which you can see in the console output), and one just inside (which is apparently missing). I just can't figure out why it would return false.

For reference, I have been watching this YouTube video, which also contains a link to a github repo with the code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkPj_IC5yeA

As a final question, really I am just curious about how to fix this 404 error and make my websocket connection work properly, and would appreciate any help/pointers to a document I missed.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: tried adding controllers for the map, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using app.Use instead of app.Map, and adding the following code:

http://pastebin.com/cSEwJqSZ